# Android: Showing the listview with custom adapter - filter the arraylist

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a peculiar problem. I am parsing a restaurant's menu card. They have it in english and in german. I have a class FoodItem as :

```
public class FoodItem {

private int foodClass;
    private String foodType;
    private String foodName;
    private String foodCost;
    private String hauptBeilage;
    private String salat;
}
```

Now, I have an arraylist of fooditems downloaded using Jsoup. I separate the german and english menu using the `String foodType`.

I want to list german menu at the start. But, I get the english menu appended to the list as well. How should I tackle this?

My downloadThread (Jsoup) is :

```
public void run()
    {
        Log.i("downloadThread", "Inside run() - Starting getFoodItems");
        getDailyGerman(); 

        getDailyEnglish(); 

//Sending a message through handler here
            }
```

In my activity, I have:

```
handler = new android.os.Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                foodItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

If I send a message through handler after `getDailyGerman();` then i get a `illegalstateexception` saying the content of the adapter has changed, but the listview is not updated.

My Adapter code :

```
public FoodItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<FoodItem> FoodItemArg) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, FoodItemArg);
        FoodItemAdapter.foodItems = FoodItemArg;
        this.setNotifyOnChange(false);
        //      if(FoodItemAdapter.foodItems == null)
        //          Log.i("Adapter", "Problem Inside Adapter Constructor");
    }

    //=========================public methods============================


    public static ArrayList<FoodItem> getDailyEnglishFoodItems()
    {
        ArrayList<FoodItem> returnList = new ArrayList<FoodItem>();
        for(FoodItem eachItem : FoodItemAdapter.foodItems)
        {
            if(eachItem.getFoodClass() == 1)
            {
                Log.i("Adapter" , "Adding English Daily Food : " + eachItem.getFoodName());

                returnList.add(eachItem);
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<FoodItem> getDailyGermanFoodItems()
    {
        ArrayList<FoodItem> returnList = new ArrayList<FoodItem>();
        for(FoodItem eachItem : FoodItemAdapter.foodItems)
        {
            if(eachItem.getFoodClass() == 2)
            {
                Log.i("Adapter" , "Adding German Daily Food : " + eachItem.getFoodName());
                returnList.add(eachItem);
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /*
         * Describes each view in the list view.
         * Get the question and find the question text, timestamp and the votes.
         * Show them in the textview which is a part of the listview.
         */

        View v = convertView;
        FoodItem foodItem =(FoodItem) FoodItemAdapter.foodItems.get(position);
        if(foodItem == null)
        {
            Log.i("Adapter", "Null Food Item");
        }
        int colorPos = 0;


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fooditem_row, null);
            colorPos = position % colors.length;
        }
```

Please help as I am stuck at this point for 3 days. Thanks.

Comment: Please list your adapter code , your getDailyGerman getDailyEnglish functions

Comment: @Mr.Me I have added the adapter code.

Comment: @Mr.Me hi.. did you get any clue? I am stuck for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once I added the items and called
notifyDataSetChanged() in the UI
thread issue solved

Comment: How do you know that the download is complete? I mean, if u call notifyDataSetChanged() before the items are added to the adapter, we will still get a empty list right?

If I call notifyDataSetChanged() after all data are inserted, then my list shows both english and german data.

Answer (score 0):

From What I understand of your question, you want to have the English items at the top of the list then the German Items. you can do that using Collection.sort method and Using a specific comparator for the task in hand.

For example:

```
final List<FoodItem> combinedList  = getDailyGermanFoodItems();
combinedList.addAll(getDailyEnglishFoodItems());
Collections.sort(compinedList, new FoodItemComparator());
//then you call the handler to update the adapter and the listView
handler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            FoodItemAdapter adapter = new FoodItemAdapter(activity.this, layout, combinedList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);   
}});
```

where `FoodItemComparator`:

```
public class FoodItemComparatorimplements Comparator<FoodItem>{

    public int compare(FoodItem item1, item2) {

        String foodType1    = item1.getFoodType();
        String foodType2    = item2.getFoodType();
                    if (foodType1.equals(foodType2))
                        return 0;
                    if (foodType1.equals("English"))
                        return 1;
                    if (foodType2.equals("English))
                        return -1;
                    return foodType1.compareTo(foodType2);
    }
```

}

Assuming foodType Value is guaranteed to be German/English only.
Also you will have to have a getter funcion inside your FoodItem Class so the comparator can access it:

```
Class FoodItem
.......
public String getFoodType(){
        return foodType;
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to display each one alone , then store the two lists inside your activity object, then when user select a language (english / german):

```
FoodItemAdapter adapter = new FoodItemAdapter(activity.this, layout, germanList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hi.. this is correct. But, i want to show german data only. And I have a menu where the user selects to change the language. Then, i should show the english data only. Right now, both are merged into the listview while i expect only one type to be present.